# how to deal with the html in my getProduct request using angular resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

product component -

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data
      .subscribe(
        (data: Data) => {
          this.router = data['product'];
        }
      );
  }
}
```

im not sure what i need to add to the html - would love to get some help -

```
<div class="productContainer">
    <img class="productContainer__image" src="img">

    <div class="innerContainer">
        <p class="innerContainer__text">text</p>
        <label class="innerContainer__text">Size:</label>
        <app-select [options]="['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']" placeholder="Size" width="100px"></app-select>
        <label class="innerContainer__price">Price: 40$</label>
        <div class="buttonContainer">
            <button class="buttonContainer__button">Add to bag</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http-product-service -

```
   public getProduct(id: string): Observable<IGetProductResponse> {
        const baseUrl = ENDPOINT;

        return this.http.get<IGetProductResponse>(baseUrl + id);
    }
```

product-service -

```
  public getProduct(id: string): Observable<IProductInterface> {
    return this.httpProductService.getProduct(id)
      .pipe(catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMessage: string;

        switch (errorResponse.status) {
          case 400:
            errorMessage = 'e';
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = 'e';
        }

        return throwError(errorMessage);
      }),
        map((response: IGetProductResponse) => response.data!),
      );
  }
```

product resolver -

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductResolver implements Resolve<IProductInterface> {

    constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<IProductInterface> {
        return this.productService.getProduct(route.paramMap.get('id')!);
    }
}
```

if u need to see more code for answer or anything just tell and i will edit the post.
thx for any help.

Answer (score 0):

in your component define product then =>

```
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => {
          this.product= data.product;
})
```

then just use 'product' that you defined in your html

```
<div>{{product.name}}</div>
```

don't forget to add product resolver in your routing

```
{
        path: "product/:id", component: ProductComponent,
        resolve: {
          product: ProductResolver,
        }
      },
```